# Having a Problem trying to install printers via powershell on c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to install printers in the pc via Powershell line that install shared printers in network, I already tried the PowerShell line and it works but I am trying to implement on C# because I have a `CheckedListBox` named `PrinterList` with the printers that could be installed. The code is below:

```
void PowershellInstallPrinter()
   {
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
       {

        string ComputerName = Environment.MachineName;
        string OfficeIndex = ComputerName.Substring(0, 3);
        string PrinterServer = (OfficeIndex + @"PP.com\");

        var SelectedPrinters = new List<string>();

        foreach (var Print in PrintersList.CheckedItems)
        {
            SelectedPrinters.Add(Print.ToString());
        }
        foreach (var Print in SelectedPrinters)
        {
            string ExecPrint = PrinterServer + Print;
            MessageBox.Show(ExecPrint);

            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\param($param1)");
            PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("param1", ExecPrint);
            PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

        }
       }
  }
```

Comment: What's exactly the problem you're having?

Comment: The printer that I select don’t get installed

Comment: I don´t have any error on the code

Comment: It looks to me like `\\param($param1)` is wrong. If I set `$param1 = "Printer"` and then execute `"\\param($param1)"` in PS I get the following output: `\\param(Printer)`. That doesn't look like a valid printer address to me.

Comment: I already tried with the spacing in and add the same result

Comment: Can you please show the PowerShell line that works when you type it in PowerShell?

Comment: `Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\networkname\"PrinterName"` This is the powershell line that I use and works

Comment: @ThaSuperalta - Can't you see that the one that works and the one that's in your app are different?

Comment: @Enigmativity that´s one the things I am trying right now but don´t know if It´s working

Comment: @ThaSuperalta - How are we meant to help if you can't see if it's working?

Comment: @Enigmativity `Collection<PSObject> results = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();` and `MessageBox.Show(results.ToString());` and don´t show me anything not sure how can I fetch the error if exists

Comment: @ThaSuperalta - I don't get the issue. `Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\networkname\"PrinterName"` works and `Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\param(PrinterName)"` does not. What's stopping you fixing this?

Comment: @Enigmativity Because the comand works running in the Powershell ISE but doesn´t Work inside of the `.AddScript`

Comment: @ThaSuperalta - Which command?

Comment: @Enigmativity `Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\networkname\"PrinterName"` and `Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\param(PrinterName)"` are the same

Comment: @ThaSuperalta - What? They are clearly different.

Comment: @Enigmativity When I enter the param they are going to be the same or do you think that could be the main problem?

Comment: @ThaSuperalta - No, the if you set `ExecPrint = "PrinterName"`, then `.AddParameter("param1", ExecPrint)` makes the command `Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\param($param1)` become `Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\param(PrinterName)`. Do you see what's going on here?

Comment: Ohhh and if I do `Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\$param1` ? What happens?

Comment: @ThaSuperalta - You tell me?